# Mysql/PHP - Displaying group_concat values in php

Tags: php, mysql

In a small project I am currently completing I have three tables in a Mysql database.

One table (main) contains information on name of match, sport etc.

Another table (channels)contain channel information such as name and link.

Final table (multichannels) contain two foreign keys which are linked to other tables fields (channelid from channels table) and (eventid from main table).

The relationship between matches/events and channels are that one match can be on many channels.

Below is the export of the tables I have set up in database for clarity.

```
-- Adminer 4.7.5 MySQL dump

SET NAMES utf8;
SET time_zone = '+00:00';
SET foreign_key_checks = 0;
SET sql_mode = 'NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO';

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `channels`;
CREATE TABLE `channels` (
  `channelid` int(2) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `link` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`channelid`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

INSERT INTO `channels` (`channelid`, `name`, `link`) VALUES
(1, 'Turkmenistan Sport',   'turkmensport.php'),
(2, 'Sportitalia',  'sportitalia.php'),
(3, 'CBC Sport',    'cbcsport.php'),
(4, 'TVM1', 'tvm1.php');

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `main`;
CREATE TABLE `main` (
  `eventid` int(3) NOT NULL,
  `event` varchar(150) NOT NULL,
  `date` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `time` varchar(5) NOT NULL,
  `sport` varchar(25) NOT NULL,
  `league` varchar(25) NOT NULL,
  KEY `eventid` (`eventid`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

INSERT INTO `main` (`eventid`, `event`, `date`, `time`, `sport`, `league`) VALUES
(1, 'Blackburn vs Leeds',   '20/01/2020',   '15:00',    'Football', 'English Championship'),
(2, 'Blackburn vs Aston Villa', '21/01/2020',   '15:00',    'Football', 'FA Cup'),
(3, 'Blackburn vs Wolves',  '22/01/2020',   '15:00',    'Football', 'FA Cup');

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `multichannels`;
CREATE TABLE `multichannels` (
  `eventid` int(3) NOT NULL,
  `channelid` int(3) NOT NULL,
  KEY `channelid` (`channelid`),
  KEY `eventid` (`eventid`),
  CONSTRAINT `multichannels_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`channelid`) REFERENCES `channels` (`channelid`),
  CONSTRAINT `multichannels_ibfk_3` FOREIGN KEY (`eventid`) REFERENCES `main` (`eventid`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

INSERT INTO `multichannels` (`eventid`, `channelid`) VALUES
(1, 1),
(1, 2);

-- 2020-01-19 01:26:30
```

My aim is to be able to echo in php one match/event details with two or more links from the multi channel table. So instead of having two separate entries for the same match with the only difference being the link field, My aim is for the two channel names (based on channelids  in multichannels table are echoed.

To do this I tried a group_concat query below:

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(multichannels.channelid)
    FROM multichannels
    INNER JOIN main ON multichannels.eventid=main.eventid 
    INNER JOIN channels ON multichannels.channelid=channels.channelid
    GROUP BY event, time, sport;
```

Running this query outputs the two channelids for the particular eventid .

The issue I am having is how can I echo the name of each channel as a link in php?

I have researched that the explode function could be used but I am unsure as to how I can get the names of the channels to display to be able to use this function.

My current php code is

```
$query = "SELECT f.event, f.date, f.time, f.sport, f.league, x.name, x.link
    FROM main f
LEFT JOIN channels x
ON x.channelid=f.channelid
GROUP BY f.event, f.date, f.time, f.sport, f.league, x.channelid, x.name, x.link";

 $stmt = $DBcon->prepare($query);

  $stmt->execute();
?>


<thead>
   <tr>
        <th>Match/Event</th>
        <th>Date </th>
        <th>Time (GMT)</th>
        <th>Sport</th>
   <th> Link</th>

</tr>
</thead>


<?php

        while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
  {

$match= $row['event'];
    $sport= $row['sport'];
    $date= $row['date'];
    $time= $row['time'];
        $link= $row['link'];
        $channelid= $row['channelid'];
        $name=$row['name'];

            ?>

            <tbody>
        <tr>
       <td data-label="Match/Event" style="font-weight:bold;"><?php echo $row["event"]; ?></td>
       <td data-label="Date"><?php echo $row["date"]; ?></td>
       <td data-label="Time (GMT)"><?php echo $row["time"]; ?></td>
    <td data-label="Sport"><?php echo $row["sport"]; ?></td>
        <td data-label="Link"><a href="https://gbcltd.club/fta/channels/<?php echo $row["link"];?>">  <?php echo $row["name"]; ?></a></td>
</tr>
                    <?php
      }
   ?>
```

Thanks in advance for any guidance anyone can provide.

Comment: Are you talking about this? `<a href="https://gbcltd.club/fta/channels/<?php echo $row["link"];?>">  <?php echo $row["name"]; ?></a>`. Seeing you mention hyperlinks for each row. What isn't working the way you'd like it to? What results are you getting as compared to desired results?

Comment: Your current query has no aggregating functions. Incidentally, to my mind it's almost perverse to GROUP_CONCAT data prior to parsing it in PHP - unless there are other aggregating functions in the same query. Anyway, for further help, see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query (I.e., show us the desired result)